# android edittext - how to limit input to latin characters only?

Tags: android, android-widget, validation, android-edittext

I have a form in my android application with an EditText on it. I need to limit input into this field to latin characters and digits only ([a-z,A-Z,0-9]) and do not allow any national characters.
How could I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry, found the answer in another post, missed it in searching.

Comment: Here is the post with the answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500060/android-input-type-for-only-non-numeric-chars)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/nameText"
 android:layout_width="177dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:inputType="text"
 android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0123456789" + (any Chars)  />
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but IMHO it's better to use InputFilter. That's what I did in the end.