# EditText of input type with number of no duplicates in android

Tags: java, android

Could anyone please tell me how to implement an `EditText` which only accepts numbers and won't allow any duplicated digits?

For example, `123` or `234` would be fine, but `112` and `223` should not be allowed.

Comment: Please expand your question...

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you would have to implement your own function. You can add the text change listener and check if it satisfies your condition.

Use the [addTextChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)) method on your EditText and make your class implement or define an inner class implementing the TextWatcher class.

Comment: Thank u for responding.I took Edittext for entering numbers just like 123,234...223.but the result I need to get is 123,234,...with no duplicates but here it allows duplicates like 112,223,...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a InputFilter and do the filtering according to your logic.

You can check this post
[Android: input type for only non-numeric chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500060/android-input-type-for-only-non-numeric-chars)